# Uniform Integrability - different characterisation - prove hint

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, measure-theory, uniform-integrability

Probability with Martingales:

---

[image]

---

For the 'only if' part

how to prove the hint? i'm guessing it's something to do with

$$E[X 1_F] \le E[X1_{\Omega}]$$

$$= E[X 1_{|X| > K}] + E[X 1_{|X| \le K}]$$

$$ \le E[X 1_{|X| > K}] + K E[1_{|X| \le K}]$$

$$\le E[X 1_{|X| > K}] + K P(|X| \le K)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But with you attempt, you do not reach the conclusion. Let $K>0$, then we have
\begin{equation}
E[|X|1_{F}] = E[|X|1_F1_{|X|>K}+|X|1_F1_{|X|\le K}]\le E[|X|1_{|X|>K}]+E[K1_F]= E[|X|1_{|X|>K}]+KP(F).
\end{equation}

Comment: I think I thought that but forgot lol thanks User ^-^